# Get specific data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to get last entry for every unique item in dataframe?
I have a this kind dataframe:

```
User | Product | Date 
u1   | p1      | d1
u1   | p2      | d2
u2   | p1      | d1
u2   | p3      | d2
u3   | p5      | d1
```

So I want to get last records of users, for example dataframe It must return,

```
user | product
u1   | p2
u2   | p3
u3   | p5
```

is it possible to get last record by date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('User', keep='last')
```

For additional options check out the documentation for the method [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)